# Unable to assigning json data in stockevents of amcharts

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, amstock

I am trying to display amCharts Stock Chart using Data Loader. Everything is working well. Now I want to display stock events using AJAX but unable to find clue to how to do it. JavaScript code drawing the chart:

```
<script>

    var chartData = [];
    generateChartData();

    function generateChartData() {
        var firstDate = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
        firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
        firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

            var a = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
            var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);

            chartData.push({
                date: newDate,
                value: a,
                volume: b
            });
        }
    }   

  AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        type: "stock",
            "export": {
              "enabled": true,
              "menu": [ {
                "class": "export-main",
                "menu": [ {
                  "label": "Download as image",
                  "menu": [ "PNG", "JPG", "SVG" ]
                }, {
                  "label": "Download data",
                  "menu": [ "CSV", "XLSX" ]
                }, {
                  "format": "PRINT",
                   "label": "Print Chart"
                } ]
              } ]
            },

            "theme": "light",
            "fontFamily": 'Open Sans',
            "color":    '#888',
        dataSets: [
          {
               title: "MSFT",
              color: "#b0de09",
            fieldMappings: [{
              fromField: 'value',
              toField: 'value'
            }],
            dataLoader: {
              "url": "data.php",
                "format": "json",
                "showCurtain": true,
                "showErrors": true,
                "async": true,
                "reverse": true,
                "delimiter": ",",
                "useColumnNames": true
            },
            compared : true,
            categoryField: 'date'
          },
        ],
        panels: [{
                title: "Value",
                percentHeight: 70,

                stockGraphs: [{
                    id: "g1",
                    valueField: "value"
                }],

                stockLegend: {
                    valueTextRegular: " ",
                    markerType: "none"
                }
            }],
                chartScrollbarSettings: {
                graph: "g1"
            },

            chartCursorSettings: {
                valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
                graphBulletSize: 1,
                valueLineEnabled:true,
                valueLineBalloonEnabled:true
            },



            periodSelector: {
                periods: [{
                    period: "DD",
                    count: 10,
                    label: "10 days"
                }, {
                    period: "MM",
                    count: 1,
                    label: "1 month"
                }, {
                    period: "YYYY",
                    count: 1,
                    label: "1 year"
                }, {
                    period: "YTD",
                    label: "YTD"
                }, {
                    period: "MAX",
                    label: "MAX"
                }]
            },

            panelsSettings: {
                mouseWheelZoomEnabled:true,
                usePrefixes: true
            }
      });
</script>
```

json result is following

```
[{"date":"2013-08-24","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-25","type":"text","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-26","type":"text","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"531","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-27","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#00CC00","value":"333","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-28","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"552","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-29","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"492","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-30","type":"sign","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"379","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-31","type":"arrowDown","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"767","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-01","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"169","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-02","type":"text","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","value":"314","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-03","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"437","description":"This is description of an event"}]
```

[Am getting following result like below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mrol.png)

[But I want result like below second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqTcP.png)

Comment: _Now I want to display stock events using ajax_ Have you written any ajax code to fetch data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eventDataLoader`](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader#can-i-also-load-event-data-the-same-way) block in your data set definition, in exactly the same way you are using `dataLoader` to load chart data.

I.e.:

```
dataSets: [ {
  title: "MSFT",
  color: "#b0de09",
  fieldMappings: [{
    fromField: 'value',
    toField: 'value'
  }],
  dataLoader: {
    "url": "data.php",
    "format": "json",
    "showCurtain": true,
    "showErrors": true,
    "async": true
  },
  eventDataLoader: {
    "url": "events.php",
    "format": "json",
    "showCurtain": true,
    "showErrors": true,
    "async": true
  },
  compared : true,
  categoryField: 'date'
} ]
```

Note that I removed `reversed`, `delimiter`, and `useColumnNames` parameters since they are irrelevant for JSON format.

Comment: It's good but it gives this error (TypeError: n.date.getTime is not a function) in console when returing json data from server . My json data is like following [{"date":"2013-08-24","type":"sign","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"}]

Comment: Try specifying your dates as Date objects instead of strings: `Date(2013, 7, 24)` instead of `"2013-08-24"`.

Answer (score 0):

@martynasma is right, but you can use `postProcess` to further process the received event data.

Here's an example I got from one of their [examples on github](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/blob/e4d7910fbaffab93c743366576c31c5569a3ce05/examples/stock_csv_data_and_events.html):

```
"eventDataLoader": {
          "url": "data/MSFT_events.csv",
          "format": "csv",
          "showCurtain": true,
          "showErrors": true,
          "async": true,
          "reverse": true,
          "delimiter": ",",
          "useColumnNames": true,
          "postProcess": function ( data ) {
            for ( var x in data ) {
              switch( data[x].Type ) {
                case 'A':
                  var color = "#85CDE6";
                  break;
                default:
                  var color = "#cccccc";
                  break;
              }
              data[x].Description = data[x].Description.replace( "Upgrade", "<strong style=\"color: #0c0\">Upgrade</strong>" ).replace( "Downgrade", "<strong style=\"color: #c00\">Downgrade</strong>" );
              data[x] = {
                type: "pin",
                graph: "g1",
                backgroundColor: color,
                date: data[x].Date,
                text: data[x].Type,
                description: "<strong>" + data[x].Title + "</strong><br />" + data[x].Description
              };
            }
            return data;
          }
       }
```